# Sql Servers mismatch for date format

Tags: sql-server

I am finding that a stored procedure works on my development SQL Server but not on my staging SQL Server.
I found that the problem is tried to store a date, the 2 SQL Servers respond different.
So I have isolated the SQL code where the problem is.
On development my datetime field is fine, but not for staging:

[image]

[image]

I need to know how to get these 2 database servers to match each other for datetime formats.

Comment: Why you don't pass a datetime to the stored-procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Check the locale settings of your Staging computer.   I bet it is set to use YYYY/DD/MM as the default date format, so it thinks you are trying to use 26 for the month, which would be out of range.

Comment: And yes, this is an answer:   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318020/so-this-is-an-answer

Comment: What I have found is that my Dev SQL Server is set to US-English and the other server is set to British. Really the 2 should be consistent but what would be the consequences for existing data if that were done? And how?

Comment: The existing data won't be changed if you change these settings.   However, there may be incorrect data already in your tables, if users were not aware of this setting and input data that wouldn't trigger an out-of-range exception, like "2017/07/01".   Maybe this would be a good time to refresh both servers from Production.   : )

Comment: @arame3333 The consequences are discussed in great detail in [Tibor's blog](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_datetime.asp). In short - use a format for your literals that is not subject to any interpretation issues.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `DATEFORMAT` configuration for it to work correctly.  Use the following:

```
Set DateFormat YMD

Declare @Logged DateTime
Set @Logged = N'2017/07/26 11:32:01.161'

Select @Logged
```

Comment: This will code around the issue, but isn't the question about how to change the server so it matches the behavior of the Dev server?